# Logging in hosted environment

Tags: c#, sql, logging

I have a website running on a (cheap) hosted company solution. The database and web server are there. I'd like to log activity that is happening on my application, down through the layers (maybe not so much Presentation). So, a service call has been made.... a business function has run in the BL... a database call was executed.... an exception was caught.

The layers are all separated. So, I guess logging to the database isn't wise, because I'd need to access the database from all layers. For example, a user selects a product. On the service method (GetProductById), I was to log that it was executed. That method then calls a GetProductById in the BL. I want to log in there too... and then finally, my GetProductById in my data accessor. I'd need database connection in all layers.

I was thinking of adding a small class that exposes one method (Log). And reference that DLL from each layer. And that DLL takes a message, and has it's own connection to the DB, with one method - write line. But, would that be too much overhead? Each 'Log' event is Open database, write, close. Is that a bit heavy? The DB is powerful... But one call could result in between 3 and 30 'Log' events (and this would help me find issues with the code, though).

The stand alone logger class appeals, as I can change it to a file logger if I wanted. But prefer the power of querying a table, for, say "ErrorLevel"s. or something.

My only issue is the overhead. Is it nothing to worry about?

Comment: What is you reason to write your own custom logging solution? Investigate if existing have all batching of log entries on write already sorted out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Logging is a cross cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), so it doesn't really make sense in the "layer" perspective.  Don't worry about if it hits a DB or not.

I would recommend using a logging library that is already created vs creating your own.  As it already takes care of all of these issues you are worried about (how to crack the best performance out of it, not taking a ton of resources, etc).  [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) is a really good one with support specifically baked in for ASP.NET websites and will work great in your other layers.  It has solutions for file or database writing.

Comment: Thanks. Tried NLog. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's my favorite.  They haven't done a release in a while (still solid though), but if you do run into an issue... pull in the latest source it has some extra bug fixes.